# Sum of hash keys in nested array in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, ruby-on-rails-4, hash

I have an array containing arrays of hashes with identical sets of keys.  I need to sum each set of keys for each array, leaving me with a single array of hashes.

```
array = [
  [{"x"=>"Apr, 2014", "price_rate"=>10, "cost_rate"=>10, "profit"=>10},
   {"x"=>"May, 2014", "price_rate"=>10, "cost_rate"=>10, "profit"=>10},
   {"x"=>"Jun, 2014", "price_rate"=>10, "cost_rate"=>10, "profit"=>10} ],
  [{"x"=>"Apr, 2014", "price_rate"=>10, "cost_rate"=>10, "profit"=>10},
   {"x"=>"May, 2014", "price_rate"=>10, "cost_rate"=>10, "profit"=>10},
   {"x"=>"Jun, 2014", "price_rate"=>10, "cost_rate"=>10, "profit"=>10} ],
  [{"x"=>"Apr, 2014", "price_rate"=>10, "cost_rate"=>10, "profit"=>10},
   {"x"=>"May, 2014", "price_rate"=>10, "cost_rate"=>10, "profit"=>10},
   {"x"=>"Jun, 2014", "price_rate"=>10, "cost_rate"=>10, "profit"=>10} ]
]
```

Which would leave me with

```
[{"x"=>"Apr, 2014", "price_rate"=>30, "cost_rate"=>30, "profit"=>30},
 {"x"=>"May, 2014", "price_rate"=>30, "cost_rate"=>30, "profit"=>30},
 {"x"=>"Jun, 2014", "price_rate"=>30, "cost_rate"=>30, "profit"=>30} ]
```

I've tried flattening them into a single array, merging (which never seems to give me the results I would expect), and reduce to add - but I'm getting nowhere.

Is there a concise way to do this?

**EDIT**
Also of note is that the number of hashes in each array can vary.  The example was for a quarter of a year, but the resulting solution should be agnostic enough to allow for as many or as few entries as the data set provides.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one (pure Ruby) way, which uses the form of [Hash#update](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-update) (aka `merge!`) that uses a block to determine the values of keys present in both hashes being merged:

```
array.flatten.each_with_object({}) { |g,h|
  h.update(g["x"]=>g.dup) { |_,oh,nh|
    oh.update(nh) { |k,ov,nv| (k=="x") ? ov : ov+nv } } }.values
  #=> [{"x"=>"Apr, 2014", "price_rate"=>30, "cost_rate"=>30, "profit"=>30},
  #    {"x"=>"May, 2014", "price_rate"=>30, "cost_rate"=>30, "profit"=>30},
  #    {"x"=>"Jun, 2014", "price_rate"=>30, "cost_rate"=>30, "profit"=>30}]
```

`trh` pointed out that my original solution modified `array`, which I had missed. To avoid that, I changed `g["x"]=>g` to `g["x"]=>g.dup`.

Comment: This is perfect.  I'm assuming that since it's updating; it's actually modifying the original 'array' object... which is fine with me for these purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Look into using deep_merge recursively.  To do this with 2 hashes you would use:

```
hash1.deep_merge(hash2) { |key, first, last| key == 'x' ? first : first + last }
```

What this is doing is merging each key value, except the first column (which should always match).   If you loop through all your arrays youy should be able to merge them into one using a similar strategy.

More info: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-deep_merge